# Footnotes : no indent, no dot

Tags: formatting, footnotes, indentation

I am trying to get footnotes without indent and without dot after the number.

Here is my goal :

[image]

Right now, I have used this to format my footnotes :

```latex
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3pt}}


\let\oldfootnote\footnote
    \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{ \fontsize{8.5}{12}\selectfont #1}}
    \long\def\@makefnmark{%
        \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont  \@thefnmark}}
        }
```

I have already read similar questions, but they did not help, the solution was never working.

Here is my code and the result :

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{BCBDC0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\topskip=6pt
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{40pt}



%*****
% Footnotes
%*****


\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3pt}}


\let\oldfootnote\footnote
    \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{ \fontsize{8.5}{12}\selectfont #1}}
    \long\def\@makefnmark{%
        \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont  \@thefnmark}}
        }

Thank you all for your help !


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\

Test\footnote{Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test }\\

\lipsum[2-5]


\end{document}
```

Thank you all for your help !

---

EDIT : result with Paul's answer :

[image]

My code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}



\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{BCBDC0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\topskip=6pt
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{40pt}



%*****
% Footnotes
%*****


\renewcommand*{\dotFFN}{}% Takes care of the dot
\setlength{\parindentFFN}{0pt}% Takes care of the indent
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\insertfootnotemarkFB}{%
  \parindent=\parindentFFN
  \rule\z@\footnotesep
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\@thefnmark}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\z@
    {\bfseries\@thefnmark}\dotFFN\kernFFN%<- Remove llap and make boldface
    \fi}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-3\p@
\hrule \@width \columnwidth \kern 2.7\p@}

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
    \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{ \fontsize{8.5}{12}\selectfont #1}}
    \long\def\@makefnmark{%
        \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont  \@thefnmark}}
        }




\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\\

Test\footnote{Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test }\\

\lipsum[2-5]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

French Babel quite dramatically redefines the footnote making mechanism. This seems to work:

```
\renewcommand*{\dotFFN}{}% Takes care of the dot
\setlength{\parindentFFN}{0pt}% Takes care of the indent
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\insertfootnotemarkFB}{%
  \parindent=\parindentFFN
  \rule\z@\footnotesep
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\@thefnmark}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\z@
    {\bfseries\@thefnmark}\dotFFN\kernFFN%<- Remove llap and make boldface
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Note: I have removed your redefinition of `\footnoterule` because that's another question. But it's not quite right: because you use a `\rule` you are getting an indent before it. I think you probably want

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern-3\p@
\hrule \@width \columnwidth \kern 2.7\p@}
```

Comment: Hello @Paul Stanley, thank you for your precious help ! It looks almost perfect. But I get a strange result. I have edited my initial post with a screenshot!

Comment: You need the redefinition of `\footnoterule` to be between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` protectors.

Comment: You are quick ! You are right, stupid mistake. Thank you very much !